# Unable to install LMD on CentOS 7.9.2009 (core)

Tags: centos, wget, malware-detection

Can someone please help me with this? I'm attempting to follow the below guide on installing LMD (Linux Malware Detect) on CentOS.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-linux-malware-detect-lmd-in-rhel-centos-and-fedora/

The issue that I am having is that whenever I attempt to use "wget" on the specified link to LMD, it always pulls an HTML file instead of a .gz file.

Troubleshooting: I've attempted HTTPS instead of HTTP, but that results in an "unable to establish SSL connection" error message (see below). I've already looked around the internet for other guides on installing LMD on Cent and every one of them advised to "wget" the .gz at the below link. I'm hoping that someone can help me to work through this.

http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz

[SSL error below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geJwL.png)

If you need further information from me, please let me know. Thank you.

Best,
B

wget --spider: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYdvJ.jpg)

Comment: Please add wget command which are you using and version of wget you are using (output of `wget --version`)

Comment: I'm just using regular `wget`. Sorry if that's not really answering the question. I'm fairly new at this and am struggling. And the `wget` version I'm using is `GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu`. Let me know if you need further information. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: okay, please run `wget --spider http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz` and add output of that to your question

Comment: Okay, believe me when I say that I've been trying for the past 1.5 days to successfully setup an email client on my CentOS machine so that I could email myself a .txt of the output, but suffice to say I've been unsuccessful at that. Therefore, I had to take a picture with my phone. See the picture I added to my initial message.

Answer (score 0):

You replace in command `http` with `https`. Try `wget` as it is mentioned in the manual:

```
wget http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz
```

Here is what I get with `--spider` option:

```
# wget --spider http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2022-07-06 22:04:57--  http://www.rfxn.com/downloads/maldetect-current.tar.gz
Resolving www.rfxn.com... 172.67.144.156, 104.21.28.71
Connecting to www.rfxn.com|172.67.144.156|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1549126 (1.5M) [application/x-gzip]
Remote file exists.
```

Comment: That's what I initially tried. The 'http' attempt just pulls a .html file.

Comment: @JesseC., it work perfect for me. Do you use proxy?

Comment: I don't believe so. I've been following the directions at this link: https://www.tecmint.com/things-to-do-after-minimal-rhel-centos-7-installation/

Comment: @JesseC., seems like you have problem with your network/internet access. I get clear access to the host

Comment: That's the conclusion I'm beginning to draw as well. I'm going to troubleshoot my network. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Okay, I can ping google.com just fine, and I can surf the web with links. Is it possible for my ISP to be blocking certain ports?

Comment: @JesseC., have you try to access some host with only http protocol? This can reveal if ISP block ports (at least port 80).

Comment: Bro, it WAS MY ISP. I called them and they're like "yeah we're blocking your Linux computer." I said, "please stop." Now we're good :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> wget --spider: enter image description here

This is interesting, you requested asset from `http://www.rfxn.com` but was redirected finally to `https://block.charter-prod.hosted.cujo.io` which seems to page with text like

> Let's stop for a moment
>
> This website has been blocked as it may contain inappropriate content

I am unable to fathom why exactly this happend, but this probably something to do with your network, as I run `wget --spider` and it did detect `(1,5M) [application/x-gzip]`.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. Could this possible be an ISP issue?

Comment: It WAS MY ISP. I called them and they're like "yeah we're blocking your Linux computer." I said, "please stop." Now we're good :D Thank you! I kept thinking "what the -bleep- am I doing wrong!?" :P

Answer (score 0):

It was my ISP. They had router-based software preventing Linux extra-network commands from getting past the gateway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).